# how can I display php codes in this code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a problem,
I can post to my form but I can't post drop down values.

### I will select a value with drop down, then I want to send these values with the form. Its posting but always posting this `454354325` value. How can I post with the selected drop down value?

Fınally!!
OK I fixed every problem except displaying php code in drop down values.

how can I display php codes in followings between drop down values?

```
     function btn(container, btnElem) {

  // Launch Dialog
  bootbox.dialog({
      message: '<div class="container-fluid">' +
      '<div class="col-md-12">' +
      '<form class="form-horizontal"> ' +
      '<div class="form-group"> ' +
      '<label for="sel1">Select list (select one):</label>'+
      '<select class="form-control" name="sel1" value="" id="sel1">'+
      '<option value="<?php include "test.php" ;?>"> Test</option>'+
      '<option value="<?php include "test2.php"; ?>">Test2</option>'+
      '</select>'+
      '</form> </div> </div></div>',
    title: "Please selec a value",
    buttons:{
      success: {
        label: "Select a Value",
        className: "btn-success",
          // Main Callback: takes the youTube URL and finds the ID, then returns the embed code
          callback: function(){
          var html="",
             $a =  document.getElementById("sel1").value,
            html= $a;

            // Add Back to Gridmanger, and wrap in editable region
            gm.addEditableAreaClick(container, btnElem, html);
          }
      }
    }
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a double comma (") missed in Html in your solution. Please find this in bootbox.dialog function and use this html

```
 <option value="TEST-VALUE"> Test</option>
```

instead of this

```
<option value=TEST-VALUE"> Test</option>
```

Comment: hi, thanks telling for this small issue, but it is can not resolve my issue.

Comment: thanks i fix it, but now i select a value from drop down, how can i post this selected value??

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's only a tip which should've been left as a comment.

Comment: You can get selected value by using this:                                                                                                                             $('#sel1').on('change' , function(){var selectedValue = $('#sel1').val();  })

Comment: Make ajax request for posting by help of $.ajax().